# SOHO routers Simultanous VOIP connections / connection tracking tables and packets per second

Tags: dd-wrt, voip

I am planning on deploying VOIP for up to 6 simultaneous calls from VOIP handsets (through the Internet using a connection with a single world-facing static IP, **over SIP, to a single IP address on the remote end**, and the sales person at my (business focused) ISP advised that SOHO routers - even fairly powerful ones won't work for more then 2 or 3 simultaneous connections, and suggested I get a Cisco router, which does not fit the environment which relies on DD-WRT boxes - including enhanced functionality of the same.  **The sales persons advise seems suspect to me.**

I accept there is going to be huge variance between a $50 home router and $500 router.   I'm interested in any data points/insights for the range of expectations - but especially routers similar to the [ASUS RT-AC68U](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_RT-AC68U)  (BCM4708A0 800 MHz dual core CPU, 128 Meg flash, 256 meg RAM)

Can anyone advise how many packets per second one can expect over such a router, and where one will start running into issues with connection tracking/to many tables.    (I can confirm that for this office, other then VOIP, usage will be quite modest, with no P2P or similar applications which make large numbers of connections) ?

Has anyone run more then a couple of SIP connections across a DD-WRT router and how did it scale ?